# HTC problems with android application

Tags: android

I have written a simple android application for auto-replying to SMS messages. It starts a service for monitoring incoming messages, then replies to them.

It works fine using the Elipse AVD as well as the 3 Motorola phones I have installed it on. I have been having problems with it causing problems with "com.android" processes on the 2 HTC phones it is installed on. The processes are random but will display an alert box with a "Force Close" button.

Can anyone help with this?
Is there something special about the HTC OS I have to account for in my application?

Comment: Are the API versions the same on all 5 phones? Anyway, 5 ANDROID PHONES??? Lucky bastard :-P

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a few steps to pin down the issue and expose it:

Obtain a Stack Trace:

- Use adb to obtain stack trace
- Use the OpenSource app "LogCollector" to collect the log if you're not near a USB connection needed by adb.

? What app is being force closed? Is it your app or is your app causing others to force close?

Most likely you'll find that a section of your code is performing work in the UI thread. When the UI thread gets bogged down, your app, and sometimes other apps will start to bog down and lead to ANR (a typical cause for force close, but not the only cause).

It may or may not be specific to HTC... It could have more to do with processor power of the device in question.